# How to fetch audio from my api with protected urls using audioplayers (flutter)

Tags: flutter, audio-player

I'm trying to play audios using audioplayers on my flutter app. My audio url are coming from an API that i've build using Java spring security and the urls to those audios are protected (I'm using token authorization (bearer token))

Answer (score 0):

[Fetching data from the internet](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) From Flutter's documentation.

And other [Networking tutorials](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook#networking).

Answer (score 0):

According to [AudioPlayer's documentation](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#other-errors-when-playing-remote-urls):

> The remote URL must be accessible and not be a redirect. If it's not an audio file, it does a redirect, it requires some headers, cookies or authentication, it will not work.

Then, AudioPlayer is not an option to use. On the other hand, [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) could support headers parameter, then you may set the authorization header:

```
await player.setUrl(url,headers: {'Authorization': tokenValue});
```